# How can I place a button on the edge of layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

How can i place a button on the edge of a layout. Half button should be on different layout and half on different.

One solution is to give negative margin but this solution is not working with my layout.

Below is the image, look at the navigation button i want exactly the same position for my button. and

[image]

Comment: Try with `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I know frameLayout but how can i place button at the edge of cardview. 

is giving negative margin is the only solution ?

Comment: I think you can do it with app:layout_anchor

Comment: post some code...we cannot tell without looking

Comment: I got the answers it can be achieved by using app:layout_anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `app:layout_anchor` and `app:layout_anchorGravity` attributes:

For example with this code,

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" 
    />
```

you anchor `myImageButton` at the bottom left of `toolbar_layout`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this works?

`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

I added this to my code and it works but without your code i can't tell you if this is the right thing

If you want to add a button to your `BarLayout` i think that the code is different.